# Scroll View hides my relative layout1

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

I am new to Android and I need some help. I have an image, scrollable text and buttons below text in my layout, but the scrollview hides the relative layout where the buttons are. I tried linear layout to, but the problem remains. Here is my code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/houseofstark"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/coverart" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrolly"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/imageView1"
    android:paddingTop="8dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/lyrics"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:text="@string/lyrics"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
</ScrollView>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/scrolly" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:background="#444444"
        android:onClick="openwp"
        android:text="@string/hbowebpage"
        android:textColor="#f9f5f5"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
        android:background="#3b5998"
        android:onClick="openFB"
        android:text="@string/facebookpage"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: As I can see here, you forgot one </RelativeLayout> at the last line

Comment: There is </RelativeLayout> at the end. App runs without errors but there's no buttons. Whole relativelayout1 is hidden by scrollview . It has something to do with the android:layout_below="@id/scrolly" . Becouse if i change this line with android:layout_above="@id/scrolly" then buttons are visible above scrollview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that the `ScrollView` has a `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` attribute. Which makes no sense, given that the purpose of a scroll view is to have content with varying size. And this ends up with the scroll view taking more space than you expect and pushing the buttons down below the screen.

Try giving the scroll view a gravity value and a height of 0.

Comment: Yes that was the problem. I fixed it by adding relative layout inside the scrollview .